# How to update value in HashMap if Key field is an instance of a class?

Tags: java, hashmap

Suppose I have a code snippet:

```
package practice;
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Temp,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put(new Temp(1,2), 5);
        m.put(new Temp(1,2), 6);
        System.out.println(m.size());
    }
}

class Temp {
    int x, y;
    public Temp(int a, int b) {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }
}
```

Output: `2`

I am trying to update the value corresponding to the object `new Temp(1,2)` but it is inserting instead of replacing it. This is why the size is `2`. How to replace the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compares the references by default, unless you implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods:

```
class Temp {
    // ...

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Temp temp = (Temp)obj;
        return temp.x == this.x && temp.y == this.y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.x, this.y);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(m.size()); // 1
```

Comment: Note that `Temp temp = (Temp)obj;` will throw an `ClassCastException` if `obj` isn't an insrance of `Temp`. It should return `false` instead.